# Trying to calculate a value from a text-box and dropdown list in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I am trying to add the values from a text-box (which keeps changing) and a drop-down list (respondents click an answer). For some reason, I am not able to capture the value from the text-box. I am not sure where I am going wrong! Can someone please help, thank you.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
var InputA = $("QR~QID88");
var dropB = $("QR~QID85"); 
var InputTotalC = $("QR~"+this.questionId);
InputTotalC.readOnly= true;

Event.observe(dropB,'change',function(e){
var dropIdB= dropB.value;
dropB.select("option").each(function(s){
if(s.value==dropIdB)
{
dropIdB=parseInt(s.text);
}
});
var InputA1 = InputA.value;
if(dropIdB>=0) InputTotalC.value=(InputA1+dropIdB)-1;
else InputTotalC.value="0";
}); 
});
```